# Comparing dates in separate rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on writing a query in Microsoft SQL server. The table I get the data from looks like this:

```
From_State || To_State || Event_Date
------------------------------------
4          || 8        || 2013-12-10 14:15:55.320
8          || 1        || 2013-12-10 14:29:36.823
1          || 4        || 2013-12-10 14:30:10.230
4          || 8        || 2013-12-10 15:56:08.077
8          || 1        || 2013-12-10 21:03:44.053
1          || 4        || 2013-12-10 21:04:17.470
```

4 = testing, 1 = idle and 8 = offline.

I need to get the percentage of the day that the equipment was testing by comparing these time stamps. I would except for this day the query would calculate that the equipment was testing for 76% of the day.

Also there will be some time at the beginning of the day potentially which will be more difficult to pick up since it overlaps with the previous day and the same at the end. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you just add what the result you are expecting from the sample data you have provided?

Comment: I guess OP needs a sum of date spans when states changes from 4 to whatever !4

Comment: In the end I just need a percentage of the day the equipment was in state 4, a date range will be provided but if I can figure out how to do it for a single day it will be easy to implement for the date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, here is my solution for this:

```
DECLARE 
      @equipment_id INT = 295, 
      @start_date DATE = '12/01/2013',
      @end_date DATE = '12/11/2013';   

-- Get initial data
WITH data AS 
( 
      -- Ensure rownumber exists to simplify operations
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY event_date) AS rownum,
            from_state_id,
            to_state_id,
            event_date
      FROM [triggers].[equipment_state_change] 
      WHERE equipment_id = @equipment_id 
      AND CAST(event_date AS DATE) >= @start_date AND CAST(event_date AS DATE) <= @end_date
), 
-- Determine time differences
data_with_time_differences AS
(
      SELECT 
            thisRecord.rownum, 
            thisRecord.to_state_id,
            thisRecord.event_date,
            CASE WHEN lastRecord.rownum IS NULL OR CAST(lastRecord.event_date AS DATE) < CAST(thisRecord.event_date AS DATE) THEN
                  DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(thisRecord.event_date AS DATE), thisRecord.event_date)
                 WHEN CAST(thisRecord.event_date AS DATE) < CAST(nextRecord.event_date AS DATE) THEN
                  DATEDIFF(mi, thisRecord.event_date, CAST(nextRecord.event_date AS DATE))
            ELSE
                  DATEDIFF(mi, lastRecord.event_date, thisRecord.event_date)
            END AS minutes_in_state,
            -- Mark Records that will be used for % calculation as 4
            CASE WHEN CAST(thisRecord.event_date AS DATE) < CAST(nextRecord.event_date AS DATE) AND thisRecord.to_state_id = 4 THEN
                   4
                 ELSE
                   thisRecord.from_state_id
            END AS recordToCalculateFrom
      FROM data thisRecord
      LEFT JOIN data lastRecord ON lastRecord.rownum = thisRecord.rownum - 1
      LEFT JOIN data nextRecord ON nextRecord.rownum = thisRecord.rownum + 1
)

SELECT SUM(CAST(minutes_in_state AS FLOAT)) /60 /24 * 100 as PercentageOfDayTesting, CAST(event_date AS DATE) as Date
from data_with_time_differences
where recordToCalculateFrom = 4
group by CAST(event_date AS DATE)
order by Date
```

This is getting my expected results. Maybe this will help someone out there. If it's unclear what I'm doing here feel free to ask.